# php error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, eclipse, sqlite

I am getting an error when running my php code:
Any ideas on where I am going wrong here?

Error says:
**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\autocomplete\test.php on line 7**

```
<?php
 $database = new SQLiteDatabase('mydatabase.db');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM guests";
 $result = $database->queryExec($sql);

 while ($row = $result->fetch()){

    echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
    echo " say ".substr($row['comments'], 0, 50);
 }


?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$result` is being populated?

Comment: your query has failed somehow, your code assumed success, and is now blundering around in the dark. What does `var_dump($result)` show?

Comment: Try using `fetch_row()` instead, see what that gives.

Comment: when I do `echo $result` it returns 1.

Comment: `var_dump($result)` returns `bool(true)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- this gives the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-objec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-exec.php

`queryExec(..)` returns boolean (`true` or `false`), you can not fetch a row from the result.

Instead use `query()` function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-query.php):

```
$result = $database->query($sql, SQLITE_ASSOC, $error);
if(!$error && $result != FALSE){
  while($row = $result->fetch()){
    ...
  }
} else {
  die($result === FALSE ? "Result was false." : $error);
}
```